# Python pandas: Compare rows of dataframe based on some columns and drop row with lowest value

Tags: python, pandas, compare, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame df:

```
       first_seen              last_seen             uri
0   2015-05-11 23:08:46     2015-05-11 23:08:50 http://11i-ssaintandder.com/
1   2015-05-11 23:08:46     2015-05-11 23:08:46 http://11i-ssaintandder.com/
2   2015-05-02 18:27:10     2015-06-06 03:52:03 http://goo.gl/NMqjd1
3   2015-05-02 18:27:10     2015-06-08 08:44:53 http://goo.gl/NMqjd1
```

I would like to remove the rows  that has the same "first_seen","uri" and keep only the row that has the latest last_seen.

Here is the an example of `expected` dataset:

```
       first_seen              last_seen             uri
0   2015-05-11 23:08:46     2015-05-11 23:08:50 http://11i-ssaintandder.com/
3   2015-05-02 18:27:10     2015-06-08 08:44:53 http://goo.gl/NMqjd1
```

Does anybody know who to do it without writing a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) and pass the columns you want to consider for duplicate matching as the args for `subset` and set param `take_last=True`:

```
In [295]:

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['first_seen','uri'], take_last=True)
Out[295]:
  index          first_seen            last_seen                           uri
1     1 2015-05-11 23:08:46  2015-05-11 23:08:46  http://11i-ssaintandder.com/
3     3 2015-05-02 18:27:10  2015-06-08 08:44:53          http://goo.gl/NMqjd1
```

**EDIT**

In order to take the latest date you need to sort the df first on 'first_seen' and 'last_seen':

```
n [317]:
df = df.sort(columns=['first_seen','last_seen'], ascending=[0,1])
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['first_seen','uri'], take_last=True)

Out[317]:
  index          first_seen            last_seen                           uri
0     0 2015-05-11 23:08:46  2015-05-11 23:08:50  http://11i-ssaintandder.com/
3     3 2015-05-02 18:27:10  2015-06-08 08:44:53          http://goo.gl/NMqjd1
```

Comment: @firelynx good point will update but wouldn't you need to sort by first_seen and last_seen?

Comment: I don't see why you would, but I would not trust myself too much with this headache I have.

Comment: @firelynx I think it would be safer as you could have overlapping dates in last_seen compared with first_seen, it seems to satisfy the OP's requirement now